# Why isn't MetaCost available in weka 3.8 GUI?

Tags: weka

I have read that MetaCost is different from CostClassifiers. I have seen that MetaCost is available in 3.6 GUI, but not in 3.8's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably is an *extension* now.

You need to install it.

Comment: Check the source code and documentation. It will list the authors. Very often, it's *not* by the original authors, and may be inaccurate. If you find such an error, report it!

Comment: Forget my comment. It was a mistake. Weka cites Pedro Domingos for the version of MetaCost I installed